# Find the correlation coefficient of X and Y

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, regression-coefficients

Suppose X and Y have a joint pdf f(x,y)=x+y, 0<x<1, 0<y<1
Find p(x,y) (rho) aka the correlation coefficient of X and Y.

ρ=Cov(Z,X)/σZσX = {E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)}/{sqrt(Var(X))*sqrt(Var(Y)}

Answer (score 0):

Cov(X,Y) = E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)
Find E(XY) by double integral of joint pdf to get value of 1/3.
Joint pdf f(x,y) --> Used to find marginal pdf f(x) and f(y).
f(x) is used to find E(X), E(X^2), and Var(X).
f(y) is used to find E(y), E(Y^2), and Var(Y).
By symmetry, E(X)=E(Y), E(X^2)=E(Y^2), and Var(X)=Var(Y).
Now we can solve the equation for (rho) p(x,y) to find the correlation coefficient.

Comment: +1 This is an appropriate way to answer such a routine textbook problem.  However, it's nearly unreadable.  If you were to enclose the mathematical expressions within dollar signs \$ they would be rendered as $\TeX$ and make your answer clearer.  BTW, there's no equation to solve: you just plug values into the formula and compute the result. The process is expedited by first observing that for any positive numbers $r$ and $s,$ $$E[X^rY^s]=\iint_{[0,1]^2} x^ry^s(x+y)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\frac{1}{r+2}\frac{1}{s+1}+\frac{1}{r+1}\frac{1}{s+2}.$$